# ion-align-items class not centering ionic HTML element

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

i want to center an ion-img inside ion-card

HTML :

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row >
  
  <ion-col size="12"  class="ion-justify-content-center">
      <ion-card  button="true">
        <ion-card-content class="ion-align-items-center">
           <!--center this image-->
          <ion-img src='./assets/images/souscription-assuré.svg' ></ion-img>
           <!--center this image-->
          <h3 class='ion-text-center'>J'ai déjà une assurance</h3>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>

  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

SCSS :

```
ion-img{
height: 20vh;
width: 20vh;    
display: block;
}
```

i used ionic pre-built css classes ion-align-items-center and ion-justify-content-center but it's not centered yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put the `margin: auto;` in the ion-img css.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a Div and use flexbox css.

.html

```
<div class="flex-container">
     <img src="path/to/your/img.png"/>
</div>
```

.scss

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , but FlexBox use is not recommended in ionic

Comment: Who says that?? You can definitely Use Flexbox in Ionic.

Comment: you better read ionic documentation ionic css pre-built classes has their own flex properties